# Linux Kernel Not Passing Complete Structure to sysfs Callback

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, driver

I am reasonably new to sysfs with respect to driver development and I seem to be observing some rather odd behavior.  To make a long story short, it seems that the kernel is not passing back complete structs to my callback.  This driver is a rather simple SPI-ADC driver that is being used to read analog thermal / voltage data.

Now, I have a hard time believing that I just found a bug in the Linux kernel in such a widely-used subsystem.  I have scoured the internet for anything that might help, but all signs indicate that this should work as is.  Other passed structures seem to be populated correctly, it is only the `attr->attr` member that appears to be `NULL`.

I should also mention that this is against the 3.2 kernel.

So, in short, what would causes sysfs callbacks to not receive a fully populated kobj_attribute struct?

**Sample Code:**

```
static ssize_t ads7960_sysfs_show(struct kobject *kobj, struct kobj_attribute *attr, char *buf)
{
int var, rc, i = 0, j = 0;
long channel = 0;

//DEBUG
printk("%s: kobj->name = %s\n", __func__, kobj->name);
printk("%s: attr = %p\n", __func__, attr);
printk("%s: attr->attr = %p\n", __func__, attr->attr);
printk("%s: attr->attr.name = %s\n", __func__, attr->attr.name);
printk("%s: attr->attr.mode = %o\n", __func__, attr->attr.mode);

/* check for silly things */
if ((attr->attr.name == NULL) || (strlen(attr->attr.name) < 1)) {
    printk("%s: invalid channel number. = %s\n", __func__, attr->attr.name);
    return -EINVAL;
}

... snip (We never get past here) ...

static struct kobj_attribute ads7960_ch0  = __ATTR(0,  0444, ads7960_sysfs_show, NULL);
static struct kobj_attribute ads7960_ch1  = __ATTR(1,  0444, ads7960_sysfs_show, NULL);
static struct kobj_attribute ads7960_ch2  = __ATTR(2,  0444, ads7960_sysfs_show, NULL);

... snip (there are 12 total ADC channels in the same format) ...

static struct attribute *ch_attrs[] = {
    &ads7960_ch0.attr,
    &ads7960_ch1.attr,
    &ads7960_ch2.attr,

    ... snip (same 12 channels as above)...

    NULL,
};

static struct attribute_group attr_group = {
    .attrs = ch_attrs,
};

static struct attribute_group *attr_group_ptr = &attr_group;

... snip ...

static struct spi_driver ads7960_driver = {
    .driver = {
        .name   = "ads7960",
        .bus    = &spi_bus_type,
        .owner  = THIS_MODULE,
        .groups = &attr_group_ptr,
    },
    .probe          = ads7960_probe,
    .remove         = __devexit_p(ads7960_remove),
    .id_table       = ads7960_id,
};

... snip ...
```

**Output Produced:**

```
[root@172.17.152.42: ]# cat /sys/bus/spi/drivers/ads7960/4
[   65.344789] ads7960_sysfs_show: kobj->name = ads7960
[   65.350026] ads7960_sysfs_show: attr = dc934000
[   65.354859] ads7960_sysfs_show: attr->attr =   (null)
[   65.360155] ads7960_sysfs_show: attr->attr.name = (null)
[   65.365746] ads7960_sysfs_show: attr->attr.mode = 0
[   65.370861] ads7960_sysfs_show: invalid channel number. = (null)
cat: read error: Invalid argument
```

**References**

http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/samples/kobject/kobject-example.c
http://kroah.com/log/blog/2013/06/26/how-to-create-a-sysfs-file-correctly/

---

**Edit 1:**

To summarize the comments below, I manually called `sysfs_create_group` from my `_init` and the `kobj_attribute` struct passed to the callback appeared to be correctly populated.  The callback now works without issue (or modification, for that matter).  As was stated below, `spi_register_driver` just calls `sysfs_create_group`.  So, why would one invoke the callback properly while the other does not?

Per comments below, below is the complete `_init` function and `spi_driver` structure.  The test that I did to manually create the paths myself was based off the `_init` code in the first reference with almost no modification.

```
static struct spi_driver ads7960_driver = {
    .driver = {
        .name   = "ads7960",
        .bus    = &spi_bus_type,
        .owner  = THIS_MODULE,
        .groups = attr_groups,
    },
    .probe          = ads7960_probe,
    .remove         = __devexit_p(ads7960_remove),
    .id_table       = ads7960_id,
};

static int __init ads7960_init(void)
{  
    return spi_register_driver(&ads7960_driver);
}
module_init(ads7960_init);
```

Comment: `attr->attr` is not a pointer, it's a `struct`, so you shouldn't be trying to print it with a `%p` format (you're just seeing the value of the first member, which is `attr->attr.name`)

Answer (score 1):

The `.groups` member of `struct device_driver` must point to a NULL-terminated list of pointers to attribute groups, not to a single pointer to an attribute group.  So, instead of `attr_group_ptr`, you need:

```
static struct attribute_group *attr_groups[] = { &attr_group, NULL };
```

...and then

```
static struct spi_driver ads7960_driver = {
    .driver = {
        .name   = "ads7960",
        .bus    = &spi_bus_type,
        .owner  = THIS_MODULE,
        .groups = attr_groups,
    },
```

However, there's a helper macro to declare both the attribute group and list of attribute groups that you can use instead:

```
static struct attribute *ch_attrs[] = {
    &ads7960_ch0.attr,
    &ads7960_ch1.attr,
    &ads7960_ch2.attr,

    /* ... */

    NULL,
};

ATTRIBUTE_GROUPS(ch);  /* declares ch_group and ch_groups */

static struct spi_driver ads7960_driver = {
    .driver = {
        .name   = "ads7960",
        .bus    = &spi_bus_type,
        .owner  = THIS_MODULE,
        .groups = ch_groups,
    },
```

Comment: I updated my code as you outline above to include a `NULL`-terminated array of `attribute_group*`.  Unfortunately, I am seeing the same behavior.  Thins brings me to an additional question: how is sysfs able to create all 12 attribute nodes if the struct is malformed somehow?  Also, is the kernel just passing back the struct that I pass in or is there some level of translation going on between init and callback?  Finally, I don't seem to see a definition for `ATTRIBUTE_GROUPS` in my kernel source; was that added in a later kernel?

Comment: @phobos51594 It looks like the macro ATTRIBUTE_GROUPS was added in the 3.11 kernel (http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/sysfs.h?v=3.11#L105).  You may have to declare those structs manually for the 3.2 kernel.

Comment: The plot thickens: if I create the group using `sysfs_create_group` in my driver init, the struct is populated correctly and the callback works without a hitch.  I would assume that the kernel just uses `sysfs_create_group` under the hood when automatically creating those attributes.  Is the attribute information stored differently when automatically generating the attributes versus creating them manually?

Comment: @phobos51594: It does indeed use `sysfs_create_group()` under the hood - [`spi_register_driver()`](http://lxr.missinglinkelectronics.com/#linux+v3.2/drivers/spi/spi.c#L254) calls [`driver_register()`](http://lxr.missinglinkelectronics.com/#linux+v3.2/drivers/base/driver.c#L222), which calls [`driver_add_groups()`](http://lxr.missinglinkelectronics.com/#linux+v3.2/drivers/base/driver.c#L184), which calls `sysfs_create_group()`.  Can you edit the question to show your driver init function?

Comment: @phobos51594: Which `kobj` are you using when you manually create them?

Comment: For my initial testing, I was using `kernel_kobj` in an identical fashion to the sample code provided in ref[1].  This worked and put everything under `/sys/kernel/kobject_example` as expected.  I also tested moving the creation code into my probe command and using `&spi->dev.kobj` to place it in my driver directory; this also works as expected.  My suspicion is that the kernel, when auto-creating attributes, is creating the files immediately however attempting to retrieve the structs later to pass back to the callback fails somehow.  Unfortunately, I have not been able to verify this.

Comment: The probe method should create them as attributes of your *device*, whereas the auto method uses the `ads7960_driver.driver.p->kobj` so it should create attributes of your driver.

Comment: This is the behavior that I am seeing.  `probe` creates the attr nodes at `/sys/bus/spi/devices/spi1.1` while the auto method creates the same nodes at `/sys/bus/spi/drivers/ads7960`.  In both cases, the nodes are created at their intended locations.  They only differ in the values passed to the callback (or lack thereof, in the latter case).  I didn't mentioned this in the previous comment (ran out of characters) but I removed the additional folder creation for `kobject_example` in `probe`.  `init` used `/sys/kernel` as I do not have a device struct at that time.  Sorry for the confusion.